# Attempt to give an alternate definition of Cotangent Space in terms of integration

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces, co-tangent-space

Let $M$ be the manifold, then we know that tangents space has basis $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_i}}$ and it acts on $g:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x_i}}$
and cotangent space has basis $dx_i$ and it acts on tangent vectors. Now using this insight, I want to reverese the process as follows:

I  first start with cotangent spaces and define it in terms of integral and then difine tangent space as its dual.

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow M$ (compare the range and domain with g). Let $\omega$ be a $1$-form i.e. expression of the form $a\;dx + b\;dy$ such that $\omega(f) = \int_f\omega$. The problem with this formulation is I cant extend it to cotangent fields in the following sense:

In the case of the tangent field, $\big(X(f)\big)_p = X_p(f)$ where as this is clearly not true for my definiton of cotangent space.

One thing I notice is that differentiation is a local concept whereas integration makes sense over a range, so the flaw I face in my definition is probably unrepairable. Anyways if possible my aim is to define cotangent space using the concept of integration (just as tangent space was defined using the concept of differentiation/directional derivative).

Bonus Question: In elementary calculus, vaguely speaking we had two important entity; $\frac{d}{dx}$ for differentiation and $dx$ for integration. So is it safe to say that the tangent space and cotangent space is the generalisation of the above two concept respectively for abstract manifold.

Comment: I can't see that $dx$ is related to integration. It is the differential. If you want to relate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $dx$ to elementary calculus I would say that *both* represent the same vector, just as column or row vector, resp.

Comment: So what is your question, again?
Regarding your last paragraph, no. The relation between integration and differentiation is more subtle in diff. manifolds. Look up the Cartan-Stokes-(Poincare?) theorem for manifolds with boundary.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Ignoring the last para, what part of my earlier question you didn't understand

Comment: @henceproved well you just said what you tried to do and why it failed. In the case of tangent vectors the space $M\to\mathbb R$ has a natural $\mathbb R$-algebra structure so you can talk about its derivations to $\mathbb R$, whereas the space of curves $\mathbb R\to M$ doesn't. There is an idea of defining some kind of spatial obects called currents as the dual of the space of forms. What I'm trying to say is that I can't tell exactly what you are asking. What do you want to know?